# php array - issue storing the value 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that stores numeric values. The issue is when I want to store the value 0:

```
.... 
$gradePoints = 0;
$students[$var1][$var2] = $gradePoints;
....
```

To check the value has been stored:

```
echo $students[$var1][$var2];
```

returns 0 ... so the value 0 has been successfully stored in the array.

However later when I search the array:

```
$value= isset($students[$var1][$var2]) ? $students[$var1][$var2] : '';

if ($value <> '')
{
do something;
}
```

If `$value` is anything but 0 it is fine but `php` seems to overlook the value 0. If I change

```
$gradePoints = 0;
```

to

```
$gradePoints = 0.1;
```

all is well. Can anyone explain why `$value <> ''` works for all values other than 0?

Comment: 'If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.' http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php p.s. so i guess that empty string is converted to 0?

Comment: Forget about `isset`. Just try `$value = 0; if ($value <> '') { do something }`

Comment: Don't use a string comparison when testing for numeric values.  Set $value to null, or false, and then test for that condition.

Comment: And for an explanation of why, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739397/php-compare-equality-emtpy-string-0-and-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this operator (**not identical**, it will check type of variable, too):

```
$value=0;



if ($value !== '')
{
//do something
}
```

You have issues because of `type juggling`™, as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: LOL mr Down Voter, please provide explanation... If you didn't noticed, i have actually provided an answer in FIRST comment to this post, BEFORE any other answer (mine included)... I think that i explained problem, and did what should be done, in this case... If OP wants to compare value with empty string (for its own reasons), if $value is 0 - this will work. You little egoistic... :)

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
$value= isset($students[$var1][$var2]) ? $students[$var1][$var2] : '';

if ($value <> '')
```

To:

```
$value = isset($students[$var1][$var2]) ? $students[$var1][$var2] : false;

if ($value !== false)
```

Course there are other ways to do it as well. Bottom line you want to avoid comparing zeros and empty strings, they will get evaluated as the same. Instead use `===` and `!==` for a precise comparison.

See here for more details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Although I have ticked this I am afraid this does not work - if ($value !== '') as Nevermind suggests does though.

Comment: If you set the value to false, and then check for `!== false`, it absolutely works. Show me your code if you are having issues.

Comment: The issue it seems with !== false is that it picked up every record ... as it included the '' ones (ie empty as opposed to null)

Comment: Then you have an issue somewhere that I can't see. Using concrete null or false is better practice than setting and checking for empty strings. Glad you got it working, but you should revisit how you are solving this.

Comment: I agree and thanks for the help. I think it is down to $value= isset($students[$var1][$var2]) ? $students[$var1][$var2] : ''; as this sets the value to be empty if not already set. Perhaps it is better to leave it as null?

Comment: Did you see both lines of code I provided to you? My solution changed that line to use false instead of an empty string.